# Trading and day trading

Tags: united-states, trading, day-trading, after-hours-trading

I would like to buy a stock in the aftermarket today and  then sell it when the market opens tomorrow.  Is this a pattern day trade? Will it meet the criteria of a swing trade instead?

Answer (score 2):

Buying a stock in the aftermarket today and then selling it  tomorrow is not a day trade.  A day trade is a round trip on the dame day.

Be that as it may, making one day trade does not make you a Pattern Day Trader. For that to occur, you need to execute more than three day trades (options and equities) in a rolling 5 business day period in a margin account, provided the number of day trades are more than six percent of your total trading activity for that same five-day period.